# Why would I create a singleton in swift instead of just dumping functions in a file?

Tags: ios, swift

With swift, isn't it possible to dump functions and variables into a file instead of implementing a singleton? Is there a good reason (like memory management or something) that I am missing, other than style concerns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With swift, isn't it possible to dump functions and variables into a file instead of implementing a singleton?

Yes, it is definitely possible. However, the same is possible in Objective-C, with the same pluses and minuses.

> Is there a good reason (like memory management or something) that I am missing, other than style concerns?

Two considerations are relevant here:

- You can make your singleton polymorphic, expose an interface, define several implementations, and pick the specific one at runtime
- You can "reset" your singleton by discarding the instance and creating a new one.
- If you need concurrency, having a singleton makes it a little easier to implement.

Comment: so I don't need to worry about anything related to memory?

Comment: @kishinmanglani The same considerations apply for module-private variables and to singletons, so you have to be careful in both cases. For example, you need to make sure that your module-private vars are not holding references to objects when they are no longer needed, in the same way that you need to do it with your singleton.

Answer (score 2):

It is very much possible to do so. Module level private variables could be used as private variables for singleton class.

For me it is rather a choice dictated by what makes more sense as a solution to the problem. The language has given us tools each with its particular usage, so use them the way they are meant to be used.

If your solution requires an object with data, state and related functionality which could have only one instance then it is better to use a singleton. This will make more sense when you or someone else will try to understand code at later time.

If your solution is just bunch of loosely related functions without data or state then it is better to use functions in a file.